# Heapster, grafana, influxdb not working with kubernetes 1.2?

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, grafana, heapster

May I know what image version for heapster, grafana and influxdb is stable for kubernetes 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Kubernetes 1.2.4 uses:

Heapster: v1.0.2 ([heapster-controller.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb/heapster-controller.yaml))

Grafana: heapster_grafana:v2.6.0-2 ([influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb/influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml))

InfluxDB: heapster_influxdb:v0.5 (also defined in [influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb/influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml))

Take a look at [this directory](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb) for all the related configs.

Comment: When I up the services, and curl to influxdb:8086/query I get following error:             `{"error":"missing required parameter \"q\""}`

Comment: I think you have to specify a query: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/services/httpd/handler.go#L271